# Realizar consulta sobre una relación ManytoMany

Tags: python, django

en mi vista estoy realizando una consulta, que me permita filtrar las "Listas" por cada "Fuente", el campo "Lista" tiene una relación ManyToMany, pero cuando muestro los datos en la plantilla a cada fuente le pone todas las Listas, sin hacer el filtro, les quedaría muy agradecido si me pueden indicar como debo plantear mi consulta.

Mis modelos

```
class Fuente(models.Model):
NombreFuente=models.CharField('Nombre Fuente', max_length=250,blank=False,null=True)
Descripcion=models.TextField('Descripción de la Fuente', null=True, blank=True)
Estado=models.BooleanField('¿Estado Activo?', default=True, null=True, blank=False)

class Meta:
    ordering=["NombreFuente"]
    verbose_name_plural = "Fuentes"

def __str__(self):
    return self.NombreFuente

class Lista(models.Model):
NumeroLista=models.IntegerField('Número Lista', blank=False, null=True)
NombreLista=models.CharField('Nombre Lista', max_length=250,blank=False,null=True)
Estado=models.BooleanField('¿Estado Activo?', default=True, null=True, blank=False)

class Meta:
    ordering=["NumeroLista"]
    verbose_name_plural = "Listas"

def __str__(self):
    return self.NombreLista



class MatrizRiesgo(models.Model):
Cliente=models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Cliente',null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
Fuente=models.ForeignKey(Fuente, verbose_name='Fuente',null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
Lista=models.ManyToManyField(Lista,related_name='matrizriesgos')

class Meta:
    ordering=["Cliente"]
    verbose_name_plural = "Matriz Riesgos"

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Mi Vista

```
class MatrizPdf(DetailView):
model=Cliente
template_name = 'Matriz/MatrizPdf.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['fuente_list'] = Fuente.objects.filter(matrizriesgo__Cliente_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    context['lista_list'] = Lista.objects.filter(matrizriesgos=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    return context
```

Los resultados en la plantilla se están cargando así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se puede ver que para cada fuente le está cargando todas las listas, sin hacer el filtro, según mi ejemplo la primera fuente solo debe cargar una lista y en la segunda fuente debe cargar 2 listas.

Mil gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

**Actualización del problema.**

Según las observaciones de Vicente, procedí a realizar el cambio en mi modelo, para que las PK de Cliente y MatrizRiesgos no sean iguales, quedando un modelo así

```
class MatrizRiesgo(models.Model):
ClienteMatriz=models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Cliente',null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
FuenteMatriz=models.ForeignKey(Fuente, verbose_name='Fuente',null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
ListaMatriz=models.ManyToManyField(Lista)

class Meta:
    ordering=["ClienteMatriz"]
    verbose_name_plural = "Matriz Riesgos"

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Adicionalmente en mi vista ajusté la clase MatrizPdf como me lo recomendó Vicente de la siguiente forma

```
class MatrizPdf(DetailView):
model=Cliente
template_name = 'Matriz/MatrizPdf.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    matriz = MatrizRiesgo.objects.get(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    context['fuente_list'] = Fuente.objects.get(matriz.Fuente)
    context['lista_list'] = matriz.Lista.all()
    return context
```

Pero me generó el siguiente error (Perdón por montar una imagen del código, pero no se como ponerlo aquí, soy nuevo usando esta comunidad).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero aprovechar esta actualización para recordar que la idea es que según un cliente seleccionado, pueda traerme las fuentes y a su vez las listas asociadas a esas fuentes ver modelo MatrizRiesgo.

Muchas gracias.

PDT: Vicente, muchas gracias por el apoyo que me estas dando con este tema.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. En la vista, estas pasando un pk, esta id a que modelo corresponde? Segun lo que veo estas ocupando la misma id para hacer query a los MatrizRiesgo_id y Cliente_id, puede que eso sea el problema.

Comment: Hola @Juan, agradezco la información. Te recomiendo que sueltes la mano con depurar este tipo de errores que encontrarás todo el tiempo mientras desarrolles en django, dado que no estaremos siempre para ayudarte. Este error que te está saliendo es un detallito, dado que el esquema general de la solución esta ok. Ahora, intentando atacar este error en particular, puedes ver que en frame 7 del StackTrace está intentando acceder al valor de self.kwargs.get('pk') y ahi lanza el error en cuestión. Si fuera tu, verificaría que esta expresión este retornando correctamente una id de cliente.

Comment: Juan Giraldo, actualicé mi respuesta. Intenta con esa y me cuentas.

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @juan-giraldo? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar observar que hay un claro error dado que estas usando la misma `pk` para referenciar dos modelos distintos, en este caso MatrizRiesgo y Cliente.

Asumiendo que la vista MatrizPDF, recibe el parametro `pk` correspondiente a la id de una instancia del modelo MatrizRiesgo, para retornar los elementos correctamente la vista podría ser:

```
class MatrizPdf(DetailView):
    model=Cliente
    template_name = 'Matriz/MatrizPdf.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        matriz = MatrizRiesgo.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        context['fuente_list'] = Fuente.objects.get(pk=matriz.Fuente)
        context['lista_list'] = matriz.Lista.all()
        return context
```

Saludos,

Comment: Espero haberte ayudado, por favor aclarame el tema de los pk, y si mi respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada.
Saludos!